# Connect to Amazon EC2 with NFS

Tags: nfs, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to my Amazon EC2 from my laptop using NFS. I've installed nfs-utils rpcbind and have the following in /etc/exports

```
/mnt/data/myuser *(rw,async)
```

Then load the changes

```
exportfs -ar
```

And start the services

```
service rpcbind start
service nfs start
service nfslock start
```

And finally open the following ports in Amazons "Security Group" for the instance.

- TCP: 111, 2049
- UDP: 111, 32806

Then on my laptop (MacBook Pro), i try the following

```
mkdir test
mount -t nfs myserver.com:/mnt/data/myuser ./test
```

But I get the following response each time:

```
mount_nfs: can't mount /mnt/data/myuser from nmdev.no onto ./test: Operation timed out
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Did you ever fix your problem? I'm experiencing the same issues with mounting an NFS share

Comment: Unfortunately I did not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and in my case I had not opened the required ports in my ec2 security group(s).

Double check that you have opened all the ports used by nfs, mountd, rpcbind, and/or portmapper. You can see the list of ports by running `rpcinfo -p` on the NFS server, for example:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx ~]$ rpcinfo -p
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100005    1   udp  34972  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  38192  mountd
    100005    2   udp  35637  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  57896  mountd
    100005    3   udp  54764  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  38193  mountd
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   udp   2049  nfs_acl
    100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100021    1   udp  48615  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  48615  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  48615  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  49687  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  49687  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  49687  nlockmgr
```

In my case I had already opened 111 and 2049, but none of the ports used by mountd. I was getting a long wait and eventually "Resource not available" when running my `mount` command, after opening the required ports it works immediately.